# Devolver ID registrado en un procedimiento almacenado en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedure

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo en php el cual realiza el registro de una venta lo que quiero es realizar la siguiente accion.
Devolver el id del registro guardado en la BD

```
$query = "CALL sp_insert_venta(:tipo_pago, :tipo_comprobante,
                :sumas, :iva, :exento, :retenido, :descuento, :total, :sonletras, :pago_efectivo, :pago_tarjeta, :numero_tarjeta,
                :tarjeta_habiente, :cambio, :estado, :idcliente, :idusuario, :nro_cuotas, :intereses_cuotas)";

                $stmt = $dbconec->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bindParam(":tipo_pago",$tipo_pago);
                $stmt->bindParam(":tipo_comprobante",$tipo_comprobante);
                $stmt->bindParam(":sumas",$sumas);
                $stmt->bindParam(":iva",$iva);
                $stmt->bindParam(":exento",$exento);
                $stmt->bindParam(":retenido",$retenido);
                $stmt->bindParam(":descuento",$descuento);
                $stmt->bindParam(":total",$total);
                $stmt->bindParam(":sonletras",$sonletras);
                $stmt->bindParam(":pago_efectivo",$pago_efectivo);
                $stmt->bindParam(":pago_tarjeta",$pago_tarjeta);
                $stmt->bindParam(":numero_tarjeta",$numero_tarjeta);
                $stmt->bindParam(":tarjeta_habiente",$tarjeta_habiente);
                $stmt->bindParam(":cambio",$cambio);
                $stmt->bindParam(":estado",$estado);
                $stmt->bindParam(":idcliente",$idcliente);
                $stmt->bindParam(":idusuario",$idusuario);
                $stmt->bindParam(":nro_cuotas",$numero_cuotas);
                $stmt->bindParam(":intereses_cuotas",$intereses_cuota);

                if($stmt->execute())
                {
                    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
                    if($count == 0){
                        $data = "Duplicado";
                        echo json_encode($data);
                    } else {
                        foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
                            echo json_encode(['message' => 'Validado', 'venta' => $row]);
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                    $data = "Error";
                    echo json_encode($data);
                }
                $dbconec = null;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $data = "Error";
                echo json_encode($e);
                //echo $e;

            }
```

Mi procedimiento almacenado:
Nota lo estuve haciendo de esta forma pero me devuelve un error

> errorInfo: ["HY000"] 0: "HY000"

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_insert_venta`(IN `p_tipo_pago` VARCHAR(75), IN `p_tipo_comprobante` TINYINT(1), IN `p_sumas` DECIMAL(10,2), IN `p_iva` DECIMAL(10,2), IN `p_exento` DECIMAL(10,2), IN `p_retenido` DECIMAL(10,2), IN `p_descuento` DECIMAL(10,2), IN `p_total` DECIMAL(10,2), IN `p_sonletras` VARCHAR(150), IN `p_pago_efectivo` DECIMAL(10,2), IN `p_pago_tarjeta` DECIMAL(10,2), IN `p_numero_tarjeta` VARCHAR(16), IN `p_tarjeta_habiente` VARCHAR(90), IN `p_cambio` DECIMAL(10,2), IN `p_estado` TINYINT(1), IN `p_idcliente` INT(11), IN `p_idusuario` INT(11), IN `p_nro_cuotas` INT(11), IN `p_intereses_cuotas` DECIMAL(10,2))
BEGIN

    DECLARE p_numero_comprobante INT;
    DECLARE p_efectivo_caja DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE p_abono_credito DECIMAL(10,2);

    SET p_numero_comprobante = (SELECT usados + 1 FROM view_comprobantes WHERE idcomprobante = p_tipo_comprobante);



          IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM venta WHERE `numero_comprobante` = p_numero_comprobante
          AND `tipo_comprobante` = p_tipo_comprobante AND `fecha_venta` = NOW()) THEN

              IF p_estado = '1' THEN

              IF p_idcliente = '0' THEN

                IF p_numero_comprobante = '0' THEN

                    INSERT INTO `venta`(`fecha_venta`, `tipo_pago`,
                    `numero_comprobante`, `tipo_comprobante`, `sumas`, `iva`,
                    `exento`, `retenido`, `descuento`, `total`,
                    `sonletras`, `pago_efectivo`, `pago_tarjeta`, `numero_tarjeta`,
                    `tarjeta_habiente`, `cambio`, `estado`, `idcliente`, `idusuario`)
                    VALUES (NOW(), p_tipo_pago,
                    1, p_tipo_comprobante, p_sumas, p_iva,
                    p_exento, p_retenido, p_descuento, p_total,
                    p_sonletras, p_pago_efectivo, p_pago_tarjeta, p_numero_tarjeta,
                    p_tarjeta_habiente, p_cambio, p_estado, NULL, p_idusuario);

                    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as registerID;
                    UPDATE `tiraje_comprobante` SET
                    `disponibles` = `disponibles` - 1
                    WHERE idcomprobante = p_tipo_comprobante;


                    IF (p_tipo_pago = 'EFECTIVO') THEN
                        CALL sp_insert_caja_venta(p_total);
                    ELSEIF (p_tipo_pago = 'EFECTIVO Y TARJETA') THEN
                        CALL sp_insert_caja_venta(p_pago_efectivo);
                    END IF;


                ELSE

                    INSERT INTO `venta`(`fecha_venta`, `tipo_pago`,
                    `numero_comprobante`, `tipo_comprobante`, `sumas`, `iva`,
                    `exento`, `retenido`, `descuento`, `total`,
                    `sonletras`, `pago_efectivo`, `pago_tarjeta`, `numero_tarjeta`,
                    `tarjeta_habiente`, `cambio`, `estado`, `idcliente`, `idusuario`)
                    VALUES (NOW(), p_tipo_pago,
                    p_numero_comprobante, p_tipo_comprobante, p_sumas, p_iva,
                    p_exento, p_retenido, p_descuento, p_total,
                    p_sonletras, p_pago_efectivo, p_pago_tarjeta, p_numero_tarjeta,
                    p_tarjeta_habiente, p_cambio, p_estado, NULL, p_idusuario);


                    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as registerID;
                    UPDATE `tiraje_comprobante` SET
                    `disponibles` = `disponibles` - 1
                    WHERE idcomprobante = p_tipo_comprobante;


                    /*IF (p_tipo_pago = 'EFECTIVO') THEN
                        CALL sp_insert_caja_venta(p_total);
                    ELSEIF (p_tipo_pago = 'EFECTIVO Y TARJETA') THEN
                        CALL sp_insert_caja_venta(p_pago_efectivo);
                    END IF;*/

                END IF;

               ELSE

                IF p_numero_comprobante = '0' THEN

                    INSERT INTO `venta`(`fecha_venta`, `tipo_pago`,
                    `numero_comprobante`, `tipo_comprobante`, `sumas`, `iva`,
                    `exento`, `retenido`, `descuento`, `total`,
                    `sonletras`, `pago_efectivo`, `pago_tarjeta`, `numero_tarjeta`,
                    `tarjeta_habiente`, `cambio`, `estado`, `idcliente`, `idusuario`)
                    VALUES (NOW(), p_tipo_pago,
                    1, p_tipo_comprobante, p_sumas, p_iva,
                    p_exento, p_retenido, p_descuento, p_total,
                    p_sonletras, p_pago_efectivo, p_pago_tarjeta, p_numero_tarjeta,
                    p_tarjeta_habiente, p_cambio, p_estado, p_idcliente, p_idusuario);
                    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as registerID;

                    UPDATE `tiraje_comprobante` SET
                    `disponibles` = `disponibles` - 1
                    WHERE idcomprobante = p_tipo_comprobante;


                    /*IF (p_tipo_pago = 'EFECTIVO') THEN
                        CALL sp_insert_caja_venta(p_total);
                    ELSEIF (p_tipo_pago = 'EFECTIVO Y TARJETA') THEN
                        CALL sp_insert_caja_venta(p_pago_efectivo);
                    END IF;*/


                ELSE

                    INSERT INTO `venta`(`fecha_venta`, `tipo_pago`,
                    `numero_comprobante`, `tipo_comprobante`, `sumas`, `iva`,
                    `exento`, `retenido`, `descuento`, `total`,
                    `sonletras`, `pago_efectivo`, `pago_tarjeta`, `numero_tarjeta`,
                    `tarjeta_habiente`, `cambio`, `estado`, `idcliente`, `idusuario`)
                    VALUES (NOW(), p_tipo_pago,
                    p_numero_comprobante, p_tipo_comprobante, p_sumas, p_iva,
                    p_exento, p_retenido, p_descuento, p_total,
                    p_sonletras, p_pago_efectivo, p_pago_tarjeta, p_numero_tarjeta,
                    p_tarjeta_habiente, p_cambio, p_estado, p_idcliente, p_idusuario);

                    UPDATE `tiraje_comprobante` SET
                    `disponibles` = `disponibles` - 1
                    WHERE idcomprobante = p_tipo_comprobante;


                    IF (p_tipo_pago = 'EFECTIVO') THEN
                        CALL sp_insert_caja_venta(p_total);
                    ELSEIF (p_tipo_pago = 'EFECTIVO Y TARJETA') THEN
                        CALL sp_insert_caja_venta(p_pago_efectivo);
                    END IF;


                END IF;


              END IF;


            ELSEIF p_estado = '2' THEN

            IF p_numero_comprobante = '0' THEN

                INSERT INTO `venta`(`fecha_venta`, `tipo_pago`,
                `numero_comprobante`, `tipo_comprobante`, `sumas`, `iva`,
                `exento`, `retenido`, `descuento`, `total`,
                `sonletras`, `pago_efectivo`, `pago_tarjeta`, `numero_tarjeta`,
                `tarjeta_habiente`, `cambio`, `estado`, `idcliente`, `idusuario`)
                VALUES (NOW(), p_tipo_pago,
                1, p_tipo_comprobante, p_sumas, p_iva,
                p_exento, p_retenido, p_descuento, p_total,
                p_sonletras, 0.00, 0.00, NULL, 0.00, 0.00, p_estado, p_idcliente, p_idusuario);

                UPDATE `tiraje_comprobante` SET
                `disponibles` = `disponibles` - 1
                WHERE idcomprobante = p_tipo_comprobante;

                CALL sp_insert_credito_venta(p_total, p_idcliente, p_nro_cuotas, p_intereses_cuotas);

                ELSE

                INSERT INTO `venta`(`fecha_venta`, `tipo_pago`,
                `numero_comprobante`, `tipo_comprobante`, `sumas`, `iva`,
                `exento`, `retenido`, `descuento`, `total`,
                `sonletras`, `pago_efectivo`, `pago_tarjeta`, `numero_tarjeta`,
                `tarjeta_habiente`, `cambio`, `estado`, `idcliente`, `idusuario`)
                VALUES (NOW(), p_tipo_pago,
                p_numero_comprobante, p_tipo_comprobante, p_sumas, p_iva,
                p_exento, p_retenido, p_descuento, p_total,
                p_sonletras, 0.00, 0.00, NULL, 0.00, 0.00, p_estado, p_idcliente, p_idusuario);

                UPDATE `tiraje_comprobante` SET
                `disponibles` = `disponibles` - 1
                WHERE idcomprobante = p_tipo_comprobante;

                CALL sp_insert_credito_venta(p_total, p_idcliente, p_nro_cuotas, p_intereses_cuotas);

            END IF;

            END IF;

        END IF;
END
```

Comment: intentaste con last_insert_id o  @@IDENTITY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el Procedimiento puedes colocar lo siguiente

```
SET nuevoId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT nuevoId;
```

si necesitas retornarlo con más campos simplemente lo agregas

```
SELECT CAMPOA, CAMPOB, nuevoId FROM Tabla
```

y ya En php solamente lo tomas con el `fetchAll`